# Searching for a movie from the 1980s: NASA chases after crashed alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie starts with a radar station, possibly the Goldstone radio telescope facility, with the workers watching an aircraft appearing and disappearing from the radar. I can't remember if the UFO crashes or was shot down.

Later a boy, that looks like a Native American (brown skin, long black hair), gets out from the craft and NASA white vehicles start chasing him in the desert... I can't remember more; besides a couple helping the alien kid. The movie had total 80s vibes.

It's not:

- [*Wavelength*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength_(1983_film)) (1983)
- [*The Flight of the Navigator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator) (1986)
- [*The Aurora Encounter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aurora_Encounter) (1986)
- [*Earthbound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthbound_(1981_film)) (1981) Looked a lot like this one, mixed with the tone of *Wavelength*.
- [*Hyper Sapien: People From Another Star*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Sapien:_People_from_Another_Star) (1986)
- [*The Sheriff and the Satellite Kid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheriff_and_the_Satellite_Kid) (1979)
- [*Witch Mountain Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Mountain_(franchise)) (1975 - 1982)
- [*The Boy From Andromeda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_from_Andromeda) (1991)
- [*Nukie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nukie) (1987)

Comment: I loved that one but that's about an A.I kid not an alien... but thanks for the memories!!!

Comment: What more can you remember about the couple? Were they a main part of the story or just for a scene or two? Husband and wife? Business partners on a trip? How exactly did they help?

Comment: the kid looks just like a human so its not like a e.t (1982)clone movie its more on the mood of Starman(1984) but with a Native american kid he looks navaho, apache you know a tribal kid... the couple help him to escape but can remember more I couldn't watch the whole movie ... and this was on 1996 or 95 in my childhood can't remember more details :c

Comment: Not explorers (1985) there is no other kid and no aliens that look like aliens

Comment: Good movies but the plots are not even close

Comment: Pretty sure it was a movie, there where always movies at that time of the day... but it could have been a failed pilot for a tv series presented as a movie? I don't know :c

Answer (score 1):

Could be The Arrival  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115571/

> Zane, an astronomer, discovers intelligent alien life. But the aliens are keeping a deadly secret, and will do anything to stop Zane from learning it.

Comment: What about the plot matches the description?

Comment: No, I loved this movie in my youth but I'm afraid that is not this one but thanks for the reminder gonna watch it again haha

Comment: This film is about a former SETI employee trying to uncover an alien conspiracy, not about NASA trying to track down a recently-arrived alien boy.

Comment: It starts with the lead watching something in the radar in a " telescope facility", and it had an alien boy who'll be part of a showdown in the desert.